# Texture Mapping - Cocos2d/OpenGL ES 1.0

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

This lightning is really affecting my game's performance because I am constantly adding and removing the lightning, but also each lighting strike is composed of 3 anti aliased lines using:

```
void ccDrawSmoothLine(CGPoint pos1, CGPoint pos2, float width)
{
    GLfloat lineVertices[12], curc[4];
    GLint   ir, ig, ib, ia;
    CGPoint dir, tan;

    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    //glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    pos1.x *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    pos1.y *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    pos2.x *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    pos2.y *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    width *= CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();

    width = width*2;
    dir.x = pos2.x - pos1.x;
    dir.y = pos2.y - pos1.y;
    float len = sqrtf(dir.x*dir.x+dir.y*dir.y);
    if(len<0.00001)
        return;
    dir.x = dir.x/len;
    dir.y = dir.y/len;
    tan.x = -width*dir.y;
    tan.y = width*dir.x;

    lineVertices[0] = pos1.x + tan.x;
    lineVertices[1] = pos1.y + tan.y;
    lineVertices[2] = pos2.x + tan.x;
    lineVertices[3] = pos2.y + tan.y;
    lineVertices[4] = pos1.x;
    lineVertices[5] = pos1.y;
    lineVertices[6] = pos2.x;
    lineVertices[7] = pos2.y;
    lineVertices[8] = pos1.x - tan.x;
    lineVertices[9] = pos1.y - tan.y;
    lineVertices[10] = pos2.x - tan.x;
    lineVertices[11] = pos2.y - tan.y;

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR,curc);
    ir = 255.0*curc[0];
    ig = 255.0*curc[1];
    ib = 255.0*curc[2];
    ia = 255.0*curc[3];

    const GLubyte lineColors[] = {
        ir, ig, ib, 0,
        ir, ig, ib, 0,
        ir, ig, ib, ia,
        ir, ig, ib, ia,
        ir, ig, ib, 0,
        ir, ig, ib, 0,
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, lineVertices);
    glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, lineColors);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

My FPS will drop to about 40, then shoot back up to 60. I've read that texture mapping the line could improve my game's performance.

I have been trying to figure this out for several weeks now, with no luck. Can someone PLEASE help me with this?

This is my current ccDrawLines and draw method

```
-(void) draw
{
    numPoints_ = 0;
    glColor4ub(_color.r, _color.g, _color.b, _opacity);

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    drawLightning(_strikePoint2, _strikePoint, _displacement, _minDisplacement, _seed, lightningPoints_, &numPoints_);
    ccDrawLines(lightningPoints_, numPoints_, texture);

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);

    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

void ccDrawLines( CGPoint* points, uint numberOfPoints, CCTexture2D* texture )
{
    //layout of points [0] = origin, [1] = destination and so on

    ccVertex2F vertices[numberOfPoints];
    if (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() != 1 )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            vertices[i].x = points[i].x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
            vertices[i].y= points[i].y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
        }
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    }
    else glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, points);

    ccTex2F texCoords[numberOfPoints];

    float width = texture.pixelsWide;
    float height = texture.pixelsHigh;

    if (CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR() != 1 )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
        {
            texCoords[i].u = (vertices[i].x * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) / width;
            texCoords[i].v = (vertices[i].y * CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR()) / height;
        }
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    }
    else glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, points);

    // Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_VERTEX_ARRAY,
    // Unneeded states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY
    glPushMatrix();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [texture name]);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, numberOfPoints);

    // restore default state
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

The texture is just a 32x32 .png file with a small blue dot.

If you look at ccDrawLines I have added the code to texture map the line. The problem with it is, gaps in the line, multiple lines being drawn, and it looks horrible.

---

***EDIT:***
I decided not to texture map the line and use ccDrawSmoothLine.

All I did was allocate the lightning in my gamelayer's init

```
lightningStrike_ = [Lightning lightningWithStrikePoint:ccp(-100, -100) strikePoint2:ccp(-100, -100)];
[self addChild:lightningStrike_ z:1];
```

Then, I created an instance method to set the _strikePoint and _strikePoint2 properties and call the strikeRandom method.

```
-(Lightning *)lightningStrike:(CGPoint)p end:(CGPoint)p2
{
    lightningStrike_.strikePoint = ccp(p.x, p.y);
    lightningStrike_.strikePoint2 = ccp(p2.x, p2.y);
    [lightningStrike_ strikeRandom];

    return lightningStrike_;
}
```

Usage:

```
[self lightningStrike:ccp(100, 100) end:ccp(100, 100)];
```

This fixed the FPS drop. After 24 hours I will answer and accept my own answer.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because you've provided too much stuff for people to comb through. Edit your question and rewrite it providing only the relevant pieces, perhaps some screenshots to better illustrate the problem and you might get more support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I decided not to texture map the line and use ccDrawSmoothLine.

All I did was allocate the lightning in my gamelayer's init

lightningStrike_ = [Lightning lightningWithStrikePoint:ccp(-100, -100) strikePoint2:ccp(-100, -100)];
[self addChild:lightningStrike_ z:1];

Then, I created an instance method to set the _strikePoint and _strikePoint2 properties and call the strikeRandom method.

-(Lightning *)lightningStrike:(CGPoint)p end:(CGPoint)p2
{
    lightningStrike_.strikePoint = ccp(p.x, p.y);
    lightningStrike_.strikePoint2 = ccp(p2.x, p2.y);
    [lightningStrike_ strikeRandom];

return lightningStrike_;
}

Usage:

[self lightningStrike:ccp(100, 100) end:ccp(100, 100)];

This fixed the FPS drop. After 24 hours I will answer and accept my own answer.